# WPF. Закрытие приложения MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

View

```
<Window x:Class="ToDo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ToDo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1100" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True">
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="499*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="40*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="31*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="367*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="644*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="#FFF9B3AA" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"></Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="#FFF46F5E" Grid.RowSpan="7"></Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFF89284" Grid.RowSpan="6"></Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="6"></Grid>

    <Button x:Name="btnClose" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
        <Image Source="Images/close.png" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnMenu" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
        <Image Source="Images/menu.png" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
        <Image Source="Images/plus.png" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnList" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
        <Image Source="Images/todo.png" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnSettings" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
        <Image Source="Images/setting.png" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
    </Button>       

</Grid>
```

Класс ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public void Close()
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Как сделать Binding к кнопке "btnClose", чтобы приложение выполняла метод?

Comment: Пробовали использовать для этого команды?

Comment: @tym32167 Да, но у меня выдает ошибку, что какая-то сборка не подключена и не реализован интерфейс ICommand. Находил в инете, но не понимаю как всё это работает, поэтому и написать под свою ситуацию не смог.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код того, что вы пробовали и полный текст ошибки

Comment: но вообще то, что вам надо, уже описано на сайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/659077/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-binding-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83-icommand-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-fluentribbon-%D0%B8%D0%B7-usercontr)

Answer (score 2):

Вся эта магия реализуется через интерфейс ICommand.
Класс команды:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action _action;

        public RelayCommand(Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = (sender, args) => { };

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
```

Ваши фактические команда внутри модели:

```
  // По-хорошему, емнип, модель не должна знать об окне, но для разъяснения подойдёт
  this.CloseCommand = new RelayCommand(() => SystemCommands.CloseWindow(myWindow));
```

Биндинг в XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand"}>
</Button>
```